# Creating a Histogram with selected parameters within the data with python (pandas, matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this csv file that I import as a dataframe using pandas with: `df_read = pd.read_csv(path_file)`

[image: my current dataframe]

I'm interested in creating a histogram that could help me study the distribution of the values for every ratio but separated by color.
Example:
A histogram that only reads the **color green** values and counts how many ratio_values are between 0.9 and 1, 0.8 and 0.899, and go on.

In this way I could understand the concentration of values that are interesting for the analysis I am doing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Import matplotlib to create the plot. Pandas is going to create an array that matplotlib could read

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

Open the file and read it as DataFrame

```
path_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'csv/product_list.csv')
df_read = pd.read_csv(path_file)
```

This next step will create a DataFrame with every column you are interested to graph.

```
df = df_read[['ratio_text','ratio_image', 'ratio_hist', 'ratio_sub', 'color']]
```

Create the color filter (in this case for green) and create the array for the histogram.

```
df[df['color']=='green'].hist()
```

Show the plots, all of them (Yes, this command alone will do the job)

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To select rows whose column value equals a scalar, `some_value`, use `==` :

`df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]`

To create your histogram, you can do it easily, just take a look at [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), you can change the bins as you want. Just check this [example](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-histogram/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.Series.hist()` method e change de `bin` parameter to set with range desired. If you want only the color green values, you can do this:

```
df[df['color']=='green'].hist()
```

I didn't set the bin value because I believe that's better you try and see the results!

Comment: In this case, how I define my axis (x, y) ?

Comment: In a histogram, you don't need to define the axis because they are implicts: the x axis is is the values of your interval and the y axis is your counter. Thus, you don't need pass any paramater to the axis because the pandas will get these automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dataframe but only rows where color is green:

```
df_green = df_read[df_read['color']=='green']
```

If you want all the histograms for the numeric columns in this dataframe:

```
df_green.hist()
```

If you wanna see it for all the colors you could iterate through the unique values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for [plt.hist()](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). If you make a list containing the limits for each bar in your histogram, for example `[0, 0.1, 0.2 , ... , 0.9, 1]`in your case, you can just feed in this list of "bins" together with the list of ratio_hist values, and it will handle the sorting by itself. To sort out the values that correspond to a row where color is green you can use a masked array or a list generator.

```
#By using masked array
ratio_values = df_read[:,3]
colors = df_read[:,4]
ratio_values = np.ma.MaskedArray(ratio_values, colors != 'green')

#By using a list generator
df = dr_read.transpose()
ratio_values = [df[3,i] for i in range(len(df[3])) if df[4,i] == 'green']

#Make the histogram
bins = [0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, 1]
plt.hist(ratio_values, bins)
plt.show()
```

hope that helps :)